# Pushing divs to a new line on mobile view

Tags: html, css

So I have a simple image-thumbnails landing page like:

```
<div style="display: inline-block;"><img style="margin: 3px 3px;" src="..." alt="" width="200" height="200" /></div>
<div style="display: inline-block;"><img style="margin: 3px 3px;" src="..." alt="" width="200" height="200" /></div>
<div style="display: inline-block;"><img style="margin: 3px 3px;" src="..." alt="" width="200" height="200" /></div>
<div style="display: inline-block;"><img style="margin: 3px 3px;" src="..." alt="" width="200" height="200" /></div>
```

On my site 4 are shown side by side on desktop. How do I force them to appear in twos in one line on mobile view?

So:
Desktop:

## # # # #

Mobile:

## # #

## # #

Comment: use media queries..put all in div..in mobile view use class which will create gap(clear:both) simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are ok with `clear:both` then go with this solution.

[Updated Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2d009out/1/)
It will give you break at that point where you want to..i have used custom media queries and change according to your need. Hope it will help..

Comment: Thank you, however with your solution it now appears one in each line

Comment: ?? they will be in 2 rows from 480px to 540px..that's why i said that use your custom media queries as m not sure in which resolution you want 2 div so..

Comment: Should I add !important in media to force this style over default styles in .css?

Comment: No No I have created gap class which is unique and this code will only work in given media queries(change according to your need) so you don't need !important.

Comment: Yes, but on my phone the pictures are shown one in each line :(

Comment: well wait..let me update my code or can you please give me the link of live site so i can help you better.

Comment: Sorry, I'd prefer not to post my site publicly

Comment: It doesn't :( Thank you for your input tho. I must be that the cms' css is interfering with it or something, I don't know.

Comment: well then sorry for not helping much as according to your point, fiddle is working but not sure why its not working in your site..sorry again.

Comment: no problem, my bad I guess. I really don't know how to bypass it

Comment: Don't worry..everyone have to start from some where but soon you will be good enough..:) believe in you..

Comment: Hmmm, it actually works with the dummy img 30px, but when I put the actual image I need, which is 226px x 226px it doesnt. What max-width should I put? 226 x 2 + 3 + 3 ?

Comment: I've made 580 max width and still no luck.

Comment: Why won't it fit, Leo the lion? With 30px is ok, but with 200px is not despite making even 900px max-width

Comment: sorry but was busy in daily task in office..now working on this..please give me few min..

Comment: I managed to do this other way skipping a proper look on desktop (as it will be only viewed on mobile). I trust however that your solution is ok. Thanks for your help Leo.

Comment: Thank you so much to believe in me..if you are getting pro in your site then feel free to share with me..i will make it secret..dnt wry..:)

Answer (score 3):

You have to add a media query to set the width of `div`s to 50% at the specified breakpoint.

```css
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  div {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="display: inline-block;">
  <img style="margin: 3px 3px;" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="" width="200" height="200" />
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;">
  <img style="margin: 3px 3px;" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="" width="200" height="200" />
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;">
  <img style="margin: 3px 3px;" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="" width="200" height="200" />
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;">
  <img style="margin: 3px 3px;" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="" width="200" height="200" />
</div>
```

Reference: [MDN - CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: Hmmm. I've added it in the code editor of a specific page (unfortunetely we are talking about CMS here) between <style type="text/css"></style> and it kinda ruined the design on mobile view making it super-narrow (regardless of the max width). Maybe I should add it in the main .css of the cms?